# What does dreamweaver auto-generated code look like?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I've never used Dreamweaver before, but I have some HTML that I am looking at and it just looks weird.  I'm left wondering if it was just auto-generated using Dreamweavers WYSIWYG editor.

Its structure is very similar to this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
<style type="text/css">
.TITLEPage { width:300px;border-collapse:collapse;background-color:white; }
.TITLEPage td { font:normal 14px/1.5em Goudy, Georgia, serif;color:#47ae32; }
***snip (all of the css is like the above)***
</style>
***snip***
<td> <a href="/css">blah
</a> <a href="/css/properties/"></a> </td>
***snip (the pattern above repeats about 10 times)***
</html>
```

It's very very simple html, just a table with links.  It's weird looking HTML, I've never seen anything like it before.  There's no indentation at all, is that indicative of dreamweaver?  The strange anchor locations, the empty anchors, and the format of the anchors are strange.

I dunno, has anyone worked with Dreamweaver before?  Is this what the code looks like?

This may very well get closed, but my search-fu failed me in this task...

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't worked with Dreamweaver at all, however, I *do* know that most, if not all WYSIWYG editors generate really messy and un-effective code (many wasted bytes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Dreamweaver will indent generated code, the provided code does not appear to be created by Dreamweaver's visual tools.